# How to remove "Transfer to Agent" default option from chat-bot option menu

Tags: einstein, bots

I want to remove the option of connecting to agent from options menu of Einstein Chatbot.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy to do this.
**Follow the below steps:-**
1. In 'Dialogs', click edit on 'Transfer to Agent'
2.Just UNCHECK the 'Show in Bot Options Menu'
[image]

[image]